# NodeJS Fetch Return always returns undefined

Tags: node.js, fetch

I'm trying to return a variable via a API, but when I go to return it, it always returns it as `undefined`

There is the function:

```
function getCityName()
{
  console.log("Trying to return city location...");
  var url = util.format('https://api.truckyapp.com/v2/map/%s/resolve?x=%s&y=%s', game.game.name, data.position.X, data.position.Y);
  fetch(url).then(function(data) {
    return data.json();
  }).then(function(parsed){
    return parsed.response.poi.realName;
  });
}
```

Code to run the function:

```
var city = getCityName();
console.log("City name is: "+city)
```

INFO: The JSON shows correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to return the final value returned by the callback from the getCityName function:

```js
function getCityName()
{
  console.log("Trying to return city location...");
  var url = util.format('https://api.truckyapp.com/v2/map/%s/resolve?x=%s&y=%s', game.game.name, data.position.X, data.position.Y);
  return fetch(url).then(function(data) {
    return data.json();
  }).then(function(parsed){
    return parsed.response.poi.realName;
  });
}
```

The above would cause getCityName to return a Promise. To get the actual value of the city, you would now have to wait for the Promise to resolve (using either await or then). Going by the standard followed, it would be:

```js
getCityName().then(city => {
    console.log("City name is: "+city);
});
```

Just to add, since getCityName would returning a Promise which might reject, it would be sensible to add a catch block while calling the function as well.